# Select specific user only if they are a "duplicate" and meet condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a result set like this:

```
UserName   Action
-------------------
Joe        Add
Joe        Remove
Fred       Add
Sam        Add
Carl       Remove
```

I only want to return the `Add` for `Joe` in this case. `Add` takes precedence. So if the user has an add record we only return that like.

```
Joe   Add
Fred  Add
Sam   Add
Carl  Remove
```

Not sure the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Be great to see what you have tried and where you got stuck. `row_number()` will sort you out.

Comment: Your title says "Select specific user only if they are a 'duplicate'" but your results show many which are not duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your real example is really as simple as your post, maybe consider something like:

```
SELECT username, MIN(action) action
FROM mytable
GROUP BY username
```

That will return one row per username (because of the `GROUP BY`). If there is some mix of "Add"/"Remove" actions, it will pick add (because "Add" will be the `MIN`). If there is only a "Remove" action (no "Add"s) it will use that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a CTE to isolate the rows I'm interested in by assigning `ROW_NUMBER()` values.

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserName ORDER BY Action) AS RowNum
   ,UserName
   ,Action
  FROM Users
)
SELECT 
  UserName
 ,Action
FROM
 cte
WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Here's the test harness:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
    ([UserName] varchar(4), [Action] varchar(6))
;
    
INSERT INTO Users
    ([UserName], [Action])
VALUES
    ('Joe', 'Add'),
    ('Joe', 'Remove'),
    ('Fred', 'Add'),
    ('Sam', 'Add'),
    ('Carl', 'Remove')
;
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2312f/1)

Edit: The ORDER BY clause in the ROW_NUMBER works here because of alphabetical order. If the list of actions is longer, you might need to impose an order with a CASE expression. For instance:

```
...ORDER BY CASE WHEN Action = 'Add' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

Which might be a good idea anyway, to future-proof your sort order.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option (a nudge less performant than Eric's) is using `WITH TIES`

```
Select top 1 with ties * 
 From  YourTable
 Order By row_number() over (partition by UserName order by Action)
```

Comment: Despite any performance hit, yours feels more elegant. Maybe just my opinion, though.

Comment: @EricBrandt I like WITH TIES on smaller tables.   Larger tables I lean towards your CTE approach.